# Is it possible to retrieve a union of items from the parse server?

Tags: android, parse-platform

when sending this query to the Parse.com server which should be fetching items from an input, I get all(redundant) of these objects.

for example, I input a range of ages 20 to 25, a city of my choosing "New York", a gender "female" and the results it gives me is: all users which are females, all users with ages with ages from 20 to 25 and users from New York.

Is it possible to get a (clean) Union of the items?

public void sendQuery() {

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> leftToRight = ParseQuery.getQuery("Users");
    leftToRight.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("age", age1);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> rightToLeft = ParseQuery.getQuery("Users");
    rightToLeft.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("age", age2);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> city = ParseQuery.getQuery("Users");
    city1.whereEqualTo("city", city);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> gender = ParseQuery.getQuery("Users");
    gender1.whereEqualTo("gender", "female");

    List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    queries.add(leftToRight);
    queries.add(rightToLeft);
    queries.add(city);
    queries.add(gender);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);

    mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseObject gender : results) {
                Object name = gender.get("name");
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) gender.get("ImageFile");
                newUsernames.add(((Object) name).toString());
                newImageUrls.add(((ParseFile) image).getUrl().toString());

            }

        }
    });

}
```